# Sudo ask password for an app if it was typed in NOPASSWD option with visudo

Tags: sudo, password

First of all, I have succeeded to eliminate sudo password from all apps simply: I create a new file in /etc/sudoers.d with `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudors.myfile` with the line:

```
ghegheg ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

it works well for all non ssh apps. But due to security reason I want to escape of sudo password only for amdgpu-pro-fans.sh app installed in /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh, but It not works.
I put in myfile the line:

```
ghegheg ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh
```

but after type command `/home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh -s 50` it ask sudo password. I tried the same thing with other apps like: visudo,

```
ghegheg ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/visudo /sbin/visudo
```

and they idem asked sudo password, if previously with `NOPASSWD: ALL`  didn't ask any password. I don't know what to do!
I list below the output of `sudo -l` command:

```
User ghegheg may run the following commands on ...
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh
```

Comment: When you type command `/home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh -s 50`, sudo isn't involved at all - unless something *inside* the script invokes other commands via `sudo`?

Comment: Indeed the script contains ```sudo chown``` and ```sudo echo``` that cannot be modified to escape sudo password, maybe It is not recommended to do it. There is the script, ```https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans/blob/master/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh```, I want to run this script on I3 at launch but It cannot because it ask for password. I don't know what to do.

Comment: So what happens when you type `sudo /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh -s 50`? The `sudo`s inside the script should not need passwords since the UID will already be 0

Comment: I delete sudo before chown and echo command and it gives me next error: ```
chown: changing ownership of '/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1_enable': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1': Operation not permitted
/home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh: line 63: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1_enable: Permission denied
/home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh: line 64: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm1: Permission denied```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sudo reads permissions top to bottom, and stops as soon as it finds a match, based on the output from sudo -l above, ghegheg  is part of a group that matches an earlier permission rule that grants sudo access with the rule   `(ALL : ALL) ALL`  therefore it is prompting you for a password, either remove ghegheg  from the earlier match, or rearrange the rules so it matches your NOPASSWORD: rule first.

Comment: The permission is written separately into file in ```/etc/sudors.d/myfile```, so I don't think this matter. But, indeed, the app is a script that contain ```sudo chown``` and ```sudo echo```, I want to write in i3 config file something like ```exec --no-startup-id /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh -s 50``` to make this settings after pc launchs, but i3 doesn't see this line, perhaps it need user password, I don't know, I have to run script manually.

Comment: This is the script: link(https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans/blob/master/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh)

Comment: when sudo is ran, it appends the extra files onto the main suderos file, then reads in the permissions.  Similar to most linux system apps, and why you see a lot of dropin files will have a number prefix in their file name, to ensure the files are read in the correct order.

Comment: if you run "sudo bash" does it ask for a password?  if it does not, one way and normally I would not recommend this, is add a line at the top of your script, 'sudo bash < " ' (note the " after <. then close the string at the end with a ",  then it will start a shell as root at the start of your script pass the rest of the script as a string to the shell created, therefore all the commands will be ran as root.  But this is a hack at best, and is not recommended as a perm solution .

Comment: Unfortunately ```sudo bash``` ask me for password, in rest it is a good idea to start script into shell as root, but I don't know how, I have even tried what you said, but unfortunately without success, maybe because ```sudo bash``` asked for password. I don't know.

Comment: is sudo bash asks for a Password it wont work unless you pass the password to the script.

Comment: "in rest it is a good idea to start script into shell as root, but I don't know how, "

To start a root shell, run "sudo bash" enter the password, and you will be in a root shell. "su" is another way to enter a root shell.

Comment: I just had another look at your script, can you try in the sudoer file you created '/etc/sudors.myfile' change the line for your permissions to:

ghegheg ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/ghegheg/Install/amdgpu-pro-fans/amdgpu-pro-fans.sh /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/env

The reason for the change is, the first line in your script instructs the shell to run your script with the /usr/bin/env it also has bash as an argument, therefore I am assuming it uses the bash shell, you need to have NOPASSWD permissions for both these programs/scripts, for it to run without prompting you for a password.